# Jquery mobile and angularjs using angular-jqm adapter . Neither Angularjs nor JQM works when page loads. output attached

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-mobile

This is my code . It is the basic template found in the angular jqm github account . There seems to be some error in the imports . As there is not much code there except that .

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html >
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile.structure-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile.theme-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jquery/css/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.css"/>
<script src="jquery/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="jquery/jquery.mobile-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-mobile.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-jqm.js"></script>
<script src="ang/angular-scrolly-docs.js"></script>
<script>
    function TextController($scope) {
        $scope.someText = 'You have started your journey.';
    }
</script>

    <script src="app.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app" jqm-caching-view >

<div jqm-page>
<div jqm-header>
<h3>Header</h3>
</div>
Hello 
<p>{{someText}}</p>
<div jqm-footer>
<h3>footer</h3>
</div>  
</div>
</body>
```

This is the output:
[image]

Neither the angularjs is working nor the JQM .

Answer (score 0):

What's in your app.js file?

First of all, you need something like "`var myApp = angular.module('app', ['jqm']);`" to make your app use angular-jqm.

Secondly, you need ng-controller (or routing code) to hook up the TextController to the current page.